# How to get multiple items in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-contacts

I’ve made a simple fragment that displays contacts and checkboxes through the simple layout `simple_list_item_multiple_choice`.

When I select the contacts, the checkboxes are marked.

I then have a button in my activity that when clicked, will create a group of the selected contacts.

My problem right now is that I don't know how to get those contacts from the ListView. What is the correct way to get these contacts? I'll be using the groups and contact information for chat later on, but at the moment, creating the group should just save an identifier for the contact to an SQLite db with the group name and each participant. I don't need information on how to set up the DB or even save to a DB. (Unless you're feeling extra helpful :) ). Right now I just want to know how to get that identifier from the listview.

Should I include `CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI`, `LOOKUP_KEY` or something else ( maybe the phone number?) in the Projection so that I can retrieve it as the identifier ? How do I actually retrieve the identifier? What do I call on the `ListView` or the `CursorAdapter` to retrieve this information?

Relevent sections in my fragment

```
private CursorAdapter mAdapter;
private static final String[] PROJECTION ={ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY};
private static final String[] FROM = {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY};
private static final int[] TO = {android.R.id.text1};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,null,FROM,TO,0 );
}


//initialize an array list to store the identifiers which are selected, assuming identifier is string
private static List<String> identifiers = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
    CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)v;
    textView.setChecked(!textView.isChecked());

    // some code here to send the selected items to an ArrayList which can be
    // passed onto my activity
   listener.onContactsSelected(identifiers);
}


private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onContactsSelected(List identifiersSelected);
}
```

relevant sections in my activity:

```
private static List<String> newGroup = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onContactsSelected(List identifiersSelected) {
    newGroup = identifiersSelected;
}

//this is the method invoked from pushing the button on my activity

public void CreateNewGroup(View view){
         //save identifiers from newGroup to the DB
}
```

Comment: In your onItemListClick you have `position` for selected items. Put them to an `ArrayList`. When you had to use it, create a `Cursor` move your cursor to that position and get the data.

Comment: @GokhanArik I've tried `mAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position)` but that just gives me an integer that I'm not sure what to do with.

Comment: Which one gives you integer?

Comment: I thought using the following would get me a string for the identifier but I get a 3 digit 'integer' instead. `mAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position).getString(0)`